# Чем плох jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

У меня лично сложилось впечатление, что кто-то из "отцов" где-то написал, де jquery работает на 5% медленнее нативного кода, а дальше как в анекдоте "[Ученый изнасиловал журналиста](http://img-fotki.yandex.ru/get/4214/stassadal.ae/0_38a3c_6200dd16_L)". Потому что с момента появления ТАКОЙ неприязни, даже боязни, использовать JQuery, я не помню.

Собственно, сабж. Чем он хорош, я и сам знаю.

P.S. Jquery-UI будет рассмотрен отдельно, как-нибудь в другой раз.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Будут подобные библиотеки получать распространение как бы сильно не пытались бить себя в грудь сторонники проектирования с нуля. И люди которые выступают против подобных библиотек на самом деле создают нечто легче проще, но как не крути тоже библиотеку в своем исполнении. Я могу покритиковать JQuery много за что, но до тех пор пока я не знаю как сделать лутше я этого делать не стану. Вот что я бы и покритиковал в сфере вебразработки так это логику в штмл шаблонах, это язык написанный на php, который в свою очередь написан на С. Кто в курсе тот примерно себе представил весь алгоритм работы таких систем. В случае же с Jquery то эта библиотека сильно упрощает жизнь если на сайте очень много анимации и динамика. И это не правда что на чистом JS код будет легче и шустрее. Точнее это правда только в том случае если вам нужно на страничке сделать одну простенькую операцию ,скажем спрятать блок или любая другая мелочь. Но если планируется целая интерфейсная база, то это глупо на мой взгляд игнорировать такой хороший вариант как JQuery.

Comment: это-то я знаю. Я же говорю: хочу докопаться до причины, почему этих "дополнительных библиотек" так боятся. Вот, например, очень жду комментария Мухина Антона... :)

Comment: только в том случае если вам нужно на страничке сделать одну простенькую операцию ,скажем спрятать блок или любая другая мелочь<br><br>
бред сивой кобылы... Т.е. вы хотите сказать что без jquery нельзя написать сложную анимацию и т.д.?

Comment: Можно, но например мой код (надеюсь, я оправдано считаю движение по спирали с затуханием сложной анимацией?) был немного меньше ядра jquery и содержал где-то 10% кошмарных костылей) Я даже не берусь утверждать, что он быстрее работал)

Comment: Ну спасибо) Я к тому, что для того, чтобы написать что-то кроссбраузерное, рабочее и качественное, нужно повторить где-то 80% функционала jquery. Т.е. суть та же, "можно, но зачем?"

Comment: Я не говорю jquery - это плохо, лишь хотел бы заметить что знание jquery != знанию javascript и постоянное юзание jquery реально заставляет мозг "засыхать" :)<br>
Более того, много раз встречал (и по сей день встречаю) людей которые вообще не знают javascript, только jquery... Может быть это не есть чем-то плохим, но как по мне - это ненормально. JQuery - лишь инструмент, кстати по поводу скорости работы - не лучшая сторона jquery, банально на игре тетрис, алгоритм один и тот-же скорость работы абсолютно различная, кароче - jquery всеголишь инструмент и не заменит язык - это важно понимать...

Comment: Кстати лично мне проще и удобнее писать на чистом JS, да и теперь(с момента моего знакомства с nodejs) я ни грамма не жалею о том что в свое время так напрягал свой мозг :)

Comment: AlexWindHope, меня мучают смутные сомнение по поводу того что у вас в практике уже есть проекты собственной разработки где очень обширно задействован пользовательский интерфейс, в противном случае вы бы не говорили такой ерунды. Это может быть не jquery, но некое опорное ядро всегда присутствует, в противном случае это не проект а каша.

Comment: @Arni - с чего вы взяли что это каша? Может для вас javascript код без jquery это и каша...

Лично мне откровенно надоели те полчища "js программистов", естественно я говорю не обо всех, но мой печальный опыт говорит о том что многие сразу(парадокс и бред полны, но факт) учат jquery минуя js...

jquery я просто не люблю( причем именно jquery, например против prototype ничего не имею ), про "не проект а каша" - очень сильно поспорю, реально ничего в jquery для себя полезного не вижу, причем абсолютно...

PS:мне пофиг на то что он востребован и на то что вы все го так любите ^.^

Answer (score 5):

Я считаю так: он плох для тех, кто не знаком с JS, т.е. для обучения. Катастрофически плох.

Это что-то типа VCL - если ты не можешь создать скинабельную кнопку на винапи, то и с визуалками ты сделаешь гэ. А вот если можешь - они ускорят твою работу в разы. Тут то же самое, нативный js дает кучу навыков и если с jquery возникнет проблема - js-программист ее решит *быстро*. А не знающий нативного js решит ее *может быть*.

Comment: Ну, уже ближе к истине. Но это педагогическая сторона. А со стороны разработчика?

Comment: Ну, на самом деле, я бы *тип* обращения вынес ближе к родному. т.е. что-то такое:

    var el1 = $({id:'myDiv1'});
    var el2 = $({class:'myDivClass'})[0];
    $({id:'div1'}).({class:'button'}).click(function(){ $({id:'status'}).text('button clicked');});

Может, это экономия на спичках, но такое безмерное пользование регулярок там, где им есть альтернатива - имхо, дикое зло. Там, где на documentReady вешается код, распихивающий по элементам события - одно, а какая-нибудь сортировка с использованием `$('#tbl1 tr.tr1 td.myTdUnsorted')` вот совсем неразумно выглядит.

Comment: В JQuery зла немало и все лишь для сомнительного удобства...

Answer (score 2):

jQuery - безусловно медленнее native-js, хотя-бы на то кол-во времени, что требуется на синтаксический разбор конструкций вида #id или div.test.
Сколько составляет замедление в % - никто не скажет, т.к. всё завязано на конкретику.

Comment: Это единственный недостаток?

Comment: Синтаксический разбор проводится во многих методах jQuery, поэтому без использования, назову это кешированием результата ( поиска к примеру ) в неких переменных,  разбор будет происходит постоянно.

Это так скажем на поверхности. Более точный анализ нужно проводить для каждого из методов/плагинов.

Comment: Не думаю, что это всегда так. Особенно, если взять средний JS-код работы с DOM - я бы поставил на то, что в среднем по браузерам и платформам jQuery-код будет быстрее (за счёт автоматической адаптации к доступным API).

Comment: А вот с этим абсолютно, в корне не согласен...<br>
Пруф не предоставите?

Answer (score 1):

Я рассматривая jquery в первую очередь как библиотеку-сборник кроссбраузерных javascript функций, простейший пример задать прозрачность элементу - вам нужно самому сделать кучу проверок, чтобы в ие задать aльфа-фильтр, старым фф и сафари дописать `-moz -khtml`, остальным просто поставить `opacity`. Понятно, что в jquery все это уже есть и вам нужно только написать одну строчку и вы будете уверенны, что это будет работать везде.

Таких примеров можно перечислить множество, начиная от навешивания событий и заканчивая `$(document).ready`. И так бы пришлось собирать или писать все эти функции, ведь они используются на любом проекте, так зачем тратить время, когда у нас есть такой мощный инструмент, как jquery?

Comment: Время временем, а дрючить свой мозг во имя опыта обязательно нужно!

Comment: Полностью с вами согласен. Многие люди научившись использовать jquery забывают даже поинтересоваться как сделать тоже самое но без оного. Видел один раз на техническом собеседовании человека, который написал document.getElementById('id').onHover = function(){}

Answer (score 1):

jQuery некоторые не любят. Да. Наверное из-за того, что когда-то `jQuery` себя не оправдал. Притом еще и расстроил. Например, из-за действительно чего-то плохого в нем. Или из-за неграмотного использования. Вот и перестают его любить, и даже бояться. Я, допустим, jQuery не использую из-за того, что он немного несовместим с ExjJs. А именно некоторые функции работают либо неправильно либо вообще не работают (по крайней мере мне так показалось). Причину не искал, но одна из догадок у меня есть: например из-за расширения или переопределения некоторых свойств или функций стандартных объектов. Или дополнения некоторых свойств к ним и с одинаковыми именами (что в первой библиотеке, что во второй). Например, есть в ExtJs собственная реализация операции `remove()` для массива (`Array`). Она выглядит так

```
Array.prototype.remove //... ... бла-бла-бла
```

Если в еще одной библиотеке будет то же самое, и логика обработки или возможность обработки некоторых данных есть а некоторых нет, то это приведет к плохим явлениям.
**Мое** мнение, что не стоит бояться таких библиотек как `jQuery` потому, что они призваны ускорять разработку, а также из-за того, что они кроссбраузерны (а значит по определению убирают много головной боли). И если мне предложат выбрать для работы одну из множества библиотек, то я выберу именно `jQuery`. На это есть четыре причины:

1. Она получила огромнейшее распространение, а это тянет следствие, что в ней очень мало багов и, если они появляются, то их *быстро* исправляют.
2. Много красивой и понятной литературы. Да еще и на русском.
3. Ее много кто использует, значит можно легко найти кого-то, кто поможет справиться с какой-то ситуацией, легко можно найти всякие блоги, форумы, где много вкусностей именно по `jQuery` и т.д. и тому подобное.
4. Доступность написания плагинов и много литература, как эти плагины писать.

С причинами покончено. Теперь мое мнение по поводу производительности: компьютеры сейчас хорошие, браузеры крутые, и микросекунды дополнительного выполнения операции не влияют на потенцию. Так что же это за фанатичность, когда идет попытка ускорить выполнение js на, допустим, 50 микросекунд??? А если есть некоторая острая ситуация в долгом выполнении, то именно эту ситуацию надо рассматривать отдельно, а не как работу всей библиотеки в целом, тормозящей выполнение на 5%.

P.S. Я много вещей делаю на нативном JS и получаю от этого большое удовольствие. Да и опыт прибавляется из-за этого быстрее. Что и советую молодым разработчикам, одним из которых являюсь я.
  _
*UPD1*:
Ах! Забыл о главном вопросе! Так чем же плох `jQuery`. Наверное тем, что пользователям приходится выкачивать из интернета со страничкой еще и библиотеку `jQuery`, что замедляет загрузку и увеличивает трафик (все же сейчас сидят на медленном интернете, фильмы онлайн смотрят :-) ); Увеличением выполнения команды на пару микросекунд;
ну и самое главное - для новичков, по-моему, лучше разобраться в нативном JS, а потом уже с пониманием садиться за `jQuery` (т.е. `jQuery` отдаляет приход глубокого понимания JS для новичков). И в последнем не уверен, но там, возможно, есть переопределения родительских функций стандартных объектов (например может быть `Array.push()`), также мне кажется нежелательным, чтобы в библиотеке к стандартным объектам не привязывали новых свойств (как был пример с ExtJs выше). Это может создать некоторые неудобства. Вот и все мои мысли.

Comment: Она получила огромнейшее распространение, а это тянет следствие, что в ней очень мало багов и, если они появляются, то их быстро исправляют.
****
Мде... IE тоже самый распостраненный в мире браузер :D

Comment: Отличие в том, что jQuery правят много разработчиков, а IE под властью только Microsoft. Тут же все причины на лицо!

Answer (score 0):

Я вот не вижу минусов в jquery, ну да, лишние килобайты, но 1 раз загрузятся и больше грузится не будут на других страницах. И это лечится [CDNом](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js)
Относительно хорошая кроссбраузерность, но всёже я стараюсь избегать jquery, боясь ие6, к примеру) Т.е., например, для работы с php я буду использовать на прямую ajax, а не jquery
**P.S.** Я задавал вопрос про фреймворки здесь недавно, jquery - это фреймворк?

Comment: В общем, фреймворк. =) Фреймворк - это frame+work - работа в оболочке, если топорно и напрямую перевести.

Comment: Спасибо) Теперь точно знаю что такое фреймворк, а то и такие языки как Orion называл кто-то фреймворком, хотя мне кажется это не так. Теперь я уверен, что это не так)

Comment: jQuery - скорее библиотека. Грубо говоря, библиотека - это то что вызываем из своего кода, а фреймворк - то откуда вызывается наш код. И jQeury ближе к библиотеке, хотя и предоставляет средства для систематизации остального кода (namespaces, plugins,и пр.)

Comment: Не скорее, а именно библиотека. Библиотека - сборник классов и функций. Фреймворк - сборник библиотек разной направленности